# Not all timers are executing

Tags: timer, omnet++

In my network in OMNeT++ 5.5.1, I have two nodes (node[0] and node[1]) which are setting the timers using the below code. The timers set by node[0] and node[1] are triggered most of the time, however there is one time during which the timer, set by node[0], is supposed to be triggered but it is not triggering. I ensured that node[1] is not setting the timer at the same time as of node[0] but still the timer is not triggering.

Here is the code:

```
MyWaitTimerMessage *myTimer = new MyWaitTimerMessage();
myTimer->setNodeId(myId);
double interval = 40.0 // In actual, the interval is calculating based on some criteria
scheduleAt(simTime() + interval, myTimer);
```

Does anyone has any idea what is the problem behind it? and what are the factors that can cause timers to not trigger?

Also, is there any way to list all the scheduled timers in OMNeT++ so that I can check whether it exists in the global list of timers or not?

Moreover, is collision between timers possible or not (in fact I have ensured that all timers are scheduled at different times, with the differences of milliseconds at least).

Thank you in advance.
Yasir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved with the help of OMNeT++ google group.

Actually, the nodes in my network are mobile, therefore the node[0] which timer was not calling, actually left the network due to mobility. Since it is no longer in the network, therefore its timer was not calling.

Below is the OMNeT++ google group link to my question that helped me to solve this issue:

https://groups.google.com/g/omnetpp/c/jQFuyhLsoVk

Best Regards,

Yasir